# How long is the pip extra index url valid from the Azure Pipeline PipAuthenticate task

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to find out for how long the credentials added to the `PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL` environment variable are valid when generated by the ADO Pipeline Task `PipAuthenticate@1`.

I'm using them to build a Docker image which I in turn use as a base image for other docker build pipelines, and sometimes the `pip install` command in those fails because the credentials are invalid.

I regenerate the base image every midnight, thinking that the credentials would last at least 24 hours, but perhaps they get invalidated when a certain number of `PipAuthenticate@1` tasks have run in other pipelines?

I cannot find any documentation around this anywhere, so hoping to find an expert here.